# Disqus plugin + Social URLs don't load in site generated using R blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, disqus, hugo, blogdown

I recently set-up a static-site using R blogdown package with Hugo theme 'kakawait/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme'. While everything works perfectly fine, I couldn't get disqus-plugin and social share-URLs to work. Site is hosted in Github Pages.

Tried changing config.toml settings and Disqus short-names, but couldn't make it work.

[image: config.toml file]

As you can see at the end of blog-article [here](https://balaca.github.io/2017/05/tamilnadu-2016-election---a-data-story/), Disqus fails with error message "We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide."  On the other hand, Social URLs (for the share icons at the end of blog) show-up in html with the baseURL prefix missing.

Disqus-Team has mentioned in one of their [help pages](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472007-i-m-receiving-the-message-%22we-were-unable-to-load-disqus-%22) that this normally happens when there are incorrectly-formatted JS variables.

In View-Source of my blog-article, `this.page.url` variable appears only with relative URL

```
this.page.url = '\/2017\/05\/tamilnadu-2016-election---a-data-story\/';
```

This is how social URLs are showing up along-side Twitter/Facebook/G-Plus icons in the page.

Twitter: `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%2f2017%2f05%2ftamilnadu-2016-election---a-data-story%2f`

Facebook: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%2f2017%2f05%2ftamilnadu-2016-election---a-data-story%2f`

G Plus: `https://plus.google.com/share?url=%2f2017%2f05%2ftamilnadu-2016-election---a-data-story%2f`

I think some issue in baseURL config setting is causing both the problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the many reasons why I don't recommend GitHub pages but Netlify. You can choose to publish with GitHub pages, but you always have to run `blogdown::hugo_build()` before you publish the site. See the [**blogdown** documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks much for your help, Yihui. With `blogdown::build_site()` (or `blogdown::hugo_build()` when Rmd files needn't be recompiled), both Disqus as well as Social-URLs work perfectly fine now. Yes I'm willing to check out Netlify but sometime down the line, when I start to get decent traffic to the blog.